# Scapy bytes are different then data representation

Tags: python, scapy

Building a dns response for www.google.com from bytes

```
dns = DNS(binascii.a2b_hex('a986818000010001000000000377777706676f6f676c6503636f6d00000100010377777706676f6f676c6503636f6d00000100010000012b0004d83acdc4'))
```

Printing the representation shows that rdata is 216.58.205.196

```
dns.an[0].rdata='127.0.0.1'
```

Printing the representation shows that rdata is 127.0.0.1

but rdata in bytes shows the old ip address instead

```
binascii.b2a_hex(bytes(dns))
b'a986818000010001000000000377777706676f6f676c6503636f6d00000100010377777706676f6f676c6503636f6d00000100010000012b0004d83acdc4'
```

d83acdc4 is 216.58.205.196 not 127.0.0.1

How can i obtain bytes with the new ip address?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this bug, neither with Scapy current version (2.4.0), nor with the current development version. You should probably upgrade Scapy to at least 2.4.0.

Comment: Hi, my scapy is scapy3 version 3.0.0

Comment: Also if i inject that packet into the network, the new ip address is shown but in bytes representation still the old one.

Comment: There is no such version as 3.0.0 I think. Where did you get this? Use Scapy 2.4.0 and your problem should be fixed.